# Click on a button inside span tag containing an svg?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have to click on the button ...
Help !!!

```
<span class = "CLASS NAME" > 
<button class = "ANOTHER CLASS NAME" type = "button" >
    <svg aria-label = "WANT TO CLICK" class = "A THIRD CLASS NAME" fill = "#262626" height = "24" viewBox = "0 0 48 48" width = "24" >
        <path ...></path>
    </svg >
</button >
```

I don't know if it matters but the html script also has another span tags with different class names but the class names for button and svg tags remain the same for all span tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to click on the button element, you can use :

```
//button[@class='ANOTHER CLASS NAME' and child::svg[@aria-label='WANT TO CLICK']]
```

We look for a button element with a class attribute equals to `'ANOTHER CLASS NAME'` and a svg child with an aria-label attributes equals to `'WANT TO CLICK'`.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily achieve this with the help of dynamic xpath. If you have any application as such then please share the URL with me and I can help you to resolve this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Xpath:

First try first one, if it's not working, use second one,

```
1) .//button[contains(@class,'ANOTHER CLASS NAME')]

2) .//button[contains(@class,'ANOTHER CLASS NAME')]/svg[contains(@aria-label,'WANT TO CLICK')]
```